# Start/Stop apache using shell script

Tags: apache, shell

I am trying to start/stop apache 2.2, using shell script. At present I am using:
    /usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl start
    /usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl stop

If there is a way to start it:
    ./StartApache.sh start

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What OS? and why aren't you using /etc/init.d/ or some such

Comment: Will you be using `./StopApache.sh stop` to stop it?

Comment: Sorry, it would be ./Apache start/stop.

Comment: Why would you want to use a script in the current directory instead of the control program in the public directory?

Answer (score 4):

Why not use the official way - the `apachectl` script?  You *can* write your own script that invokes the official script, but why bother?  And you certainly don't want it in your current directory - you have lots of directories, don't you?  You might add your script to a directory on your PATH (such as `$HOME/bin`, assuming you have that directory and it appears on your PATH); you might simply add a symbolic link to a directory on your PATH that points at the official script.

If you must do it, then:

```
cd $HOME/bin &&
ln -s /usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl ./Apache
```

Now you can do:

```
./Apache start
./Apache stop
./Apache restart
```

when you're in your `$HOME/bin` directory, and (more usually) just:

```
Apache start
Apache stop
Apache restart
```

without any path specified, so the shell finds the script for you.  Of course, you could also simply add `/usr/local/apache/bin` to your PATH and use `apachectl` directly.